# How to make these axis expressions explicit by Matlab axes?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axes

Diff conditions: how to change the [`axis`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) expressions to [`axes`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html); implicit handling of figure axis cause unstable conditions etc graphs are plotted in wrong figures, ...
The function `axis` is a shorthand for simplified modification

> The axis (not axes) function provides simplified access to commonly used properties that control the scaling and appearance of axes.

Code which is unstable

```
hFig2=figure(hFig2); 
hax2=axes(hFig2); 
plot(u); 
axis xy;
axis([0 (size(u,1)/1 - 0) min(u) max(u)]); 
axis off;
```

Pseudocode to stabilise it but wrong syntax

```
hFig2=figure(hFig2); 
hax2=axes(hFig2); 
plot(u, hFig2); 
axis('xy', hFig2);
axis([0 (size(u,1)/1 - 0) min(u) max(u)], hFig2); 
axis('off', hFig2);
```

- Error

  ```
  Error using message
  In 'MATLAB:axis:UnknownOption', data type supplied is incorrect for parameter {1}.

  Error in axis (line 204)
                  error(message('MATLAB:axis:UnknownOption', cur_arg));

  Error in code_1s (line 563)
      axis('xy', hFig2);
  ```

Matlab: 2016a
OS: Debian 8.5
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Documentation: [axis](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html), [axes](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axis` operates on a specific `axes` (or an array of `axes` objects) *not* a `figure`. If you want it to be stable and apply `axis` to a *specific* `axes`, just pass that `axes` handle as the first input to `axis`

```
axis(hax2, 'xy')
axis(hax2, [0 (size(u,1)/1 - 0) min(u) max(u)])
axis(hax2, 'off')
```

Comment: @Masi I don't understand what you're asking. Why are you calling `axes()` on an existing axes (`b2`) and why do you create that subplot again: `b2 = subplot(2,2,2)`? It may hope to show your real code in this question or a new question.

Comment: @Masi Oh ok I see. How about your create `b1` and `b2` with `axes` rather than `subplot`? You don't actually need to use `subplot` if you are going to manually position them.

Comment: @Masi I would but I'm not sure what you want. I don't know what you mean by "but there you do not use any axes() to assign the subplot size". `axes()` has nothing to do with the size...

Comment: @Masi Right but you don't need `axes`. What purpose did you think it served that you needed it?

Comment: @Masi Well I misspoke. I thought you were creating them with `subplot` and then changing their position but you're only changing their x and y limits so ignore that comment. What was wrong with what you posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816988/how-to-make-these-axis-expressions-explicit-by-matlab-axes/39817264?noredirect=1#comment66925575_39817264)